# Python pyautogui/pynput click function

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, pyautogui, pynput

I tried making a simple autoclicker but it is not working for me.My cursor is moving slowly as f***.
You guys have an idea how to fix this?

Problem: line 11, pyautogui.click(button='left') is not clicking.

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener, Button, Controller
import pyautogui

# This function will be called when any key of mouse is pressed
def on_click(*args):
    # see what argument is passed.
    print(args)
    if args[-1]:
        # Do something when the mouse key is pressed.
        print('The "{}" mouse key has held down'.format(args[-2].name))
        pyautogui.click(button='left')           # <--- lagging mouse

    elif not args[-1]:
        # Do something when the mouse key is released.
        print('The "{}" mouse key is released'.format(args[-2].name))


# Open Listener for mouse key presses
with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    # Listen to the mouse key presses
    listener.join()
```

Comment: By the way i already tried with pynput too: 

mouse = Controller()
mouse.click(Button.left, 1)

Also not wotking

Comment: You could disable the fail safe to take out the pause between each action (you might have to reboot to stop the program if it is doing the wrong then rather than being able to move your mouse to the top left to stop the program) - pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False

Comment: sadly not working for me but thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Supposing this is on a while or for loop, you can make it faster by changing the pyautogui.pause variable. Write this on top of your code:

```
pyautogui.PAUSE = .001
```

It specifies the delay between each pyautogui function call.