# Taking Single Click Event and Propagating it to Multiple Areas - python, pynput, pyautogui

Tags: python, python-3.x, mouselistener, pyautogui, pynput

Having trouble turning 1 mouse click into multiple mouse clicks. Basically what I want to do is to control multiple windows at once. I want to click on one master window and have the clicks propagate to the subsequent windows. In this snippet there are 4 windows and I track them via determining the `offset` between it and the master window.

I'm using python3 with pynput for the mouse listener and pyautogui for mouse control.

What I'm having a problem with is setting up the mouse listener such that it listens to my actual clicks but ignores the programmatic clicks. Right now, I think it's getting stuck in an infinite loop where my initial click triggers the `on_click` event, propagates the clicks, each triggering an additional `on_click` event, propagates the clicks, etc. When I run the below code it starts fine, and then when I first click it just heavily lags my mouse for a minute before return back to normal with no mouse listener active anymore. My guess is that a failsafe kicks in to return it to normal.

**Things I have tried:**

- using pynput for listener and control - this does not change the outcome
- stopping the listener and creating a new one after propagated clicks have finished - bad hacky solution that still did not change the outcome
- semaphore locking with `_value` peeking to ignore events if semaphore has already been acquired - also hacky and did not work
- calling `propagateActions` via threading and waiting for completion before returning from `on_click` event - did not work
- commenting out `pyautogui.click()` - this allows for expected behavior to move the mouse to the subsequent locations and return it back to its initial position after. Without the click, it works perfect. With the click, it lags and the listener dies.
- searching stackoverflow - [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65080195/python-pyautogui-pynput-click-function) bears a resemblance in terms of outcome, but is unanswered and is trying to achieve something different.

My snippet is below:

```py
from pynput import mouse, keyboard
import pyautogui

pyautogui.PAUSE = 0.01
mouseListener = None
killSwitch = False

# this is just a keyboard listener for a kill switch
def on_release(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.f1:
        global killSwitch
        print('@@@ Kill switch activated @@@')
        killSwitch = True

# on mouse release I want to propogate a click to 4 other areas
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    print('{0} at {1}'.format('Pressed' if pressed else 'Released', (x, y)))
    if not pressed:
        propogateActions(x, y, button)

# propogates clicks
def propogateActions(x, y, button):
    print('propogating actions to {0} windows'.format(len(offsets)+1))
    for offset in offsets:
        pyautogui.moveTo(x+offset.x, y+offset.y)
        print('mouse moved')
        if button == mouse.Button.left:
            print('left clicking at ({0}, {1})'.format(x+offset.x, y+offset.y))
            pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)

# point class for ease of use
class Point():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Point(x={0}, y={1})'.format(self.x, self.y)

# main method
def doTheThing():
    print('started')
    while not killSwitch:
        pass

# initializations and starting listeners
# offsets tracks how far the subsequent clicks are from the initial click point
offsets = [Point(50, 0), Point(50, 50), Point(0, 50)]
keyboardListener = keyboard.Listener(on_release=on_release)
mouseListener = mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click)
keyboardListener.start()
mouseListener.start()
doTheThing()
```

**My Question:**

- Is there some way to listen only for "real" clicks and not programmatic clicks?
- If not, can I pause the mouse listener and then restart it some way after the propagated clicks have occurred?

This is the small section of code that's relevant to the issue at hand. `offsets` has an initialization that sets it more appropriately and there's other bells and whistles, but this is the section relevant to the problem. I appreciate your help.

Comment: For system all these clicks are real.

Comment: if you click in one window then maybe you should check mouse position and propage only if click are in some area.

Comment: you can also measure time between clicks and skip clicks which are few milliseconds after another click.

Comment: ya I was more asking if there was something different between a user click and a programmatic click. From my program, it does not appear so. For your other 2 comments, those could work but would limit the solution. The master window would only be able to be in a fixed location and the time would restrict how quickly I can make actions. Both brittle solutions, but could work. I ended up finding the correct solution though. Answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer! Had to go a layer deeper.

Pynput has a [method of suppressing events](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=suppress#how-do-i-suppress-specific-events-only) that exposes the [win32 data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-msllhookstruct) behind the click event. Ran a test of one of my clicks vs a `pyautogui.click()` and lo-and-behold there is a difference. The `data.flags` was set to value `0` on a user click event and set to value `1` on a programmatic click.

That's good enough for me to filter on. This is the pertinent filter:

```py
def win32_event_filter(msg, data):
    if data.flags:
        print('suppressing event')
        return False
```

added that to my above code and changed the

```
mouseListener = mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click)
```

to

```
mouseListener = mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click, win32_event_filter=win32_event_filter)
```

and it works!

My real clicks prevail, programmatic clicks are propagated, and I am not stuck in an infinite loop. Hope this helps if others run into this issue.

Comment: I like it because you go layer deeper. Big +1 for your effort.