# pynput doing mouse click action inside on_click

Tags: python, pynput

im having a problem using mouse on_click function of pynput whenever the supplied function also performs a mouse click

quite similar with this post
[Taking Single Click Event and Propagating it to Multiple Areas - python, pynput, pyautogui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67223061/taking-single-click-event-and-propagating-it-to-multiple-areas-python-pynput)

but i cant seem to make it work it just randomly freeze

```
from pynput.mouse import Controller, Button
from pynput import mouse
import pyautogui as pa

controller = Controller()

def win32_event_filter(msg, data):
    if data.flags:
        print('suppressing event')
        return False

class EventHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mouse_listener = None

    def start(self):
        self.mouse_listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=self.on_click, win32_event_filter=win32_event_filter)
        self.mouse_listener.start()
        self.mouse_listener.join()

    def on_click(self, x, y, button, pressed):
        if pressed:
            if button == Button.left:
                self.do_action()
            if button == Button.right:
                self.perform_click()

    def do_action(self):
        print('doing action')
        print('action done')

    def perform_click(self):
        pa.click() # crashes


if __name__ == '__main__':
    event_handler = EventHandler()
    event_handler.start()
```

script crashes when i do right mouse click
any work around on this? cheers

Comment: You can try using [pyautogui](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI).