# Double-click program in Python

Tags: python, pyautogui, pynput

I wrote a program in Python that should perform a double-click. In other words, when I press the left mouse button, the program should click again. However, when I click the left mouse button, the cursor starts to lag severely, even though the program clicked only once. Here's the code of the program:

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener
import pyautogui

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if button == button.left and pressed:
        print("wawawa")
        pyautogui.click()

with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

The console printed only two 'wawawa' messages. In other words, the program clicked only once

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65080195/python-pyautogui-pynput-click-function): but no answers.

Comment: You might need to sleep for 20ms before clicking again.

Comment: Can confirm that this occurs in `pyWinhook` which is a fork of `pyHook` and is not related to `pyautogui`. It still freezes with `pyWinhook` if I replace second click with a `time.sleep(1)`: it lags for 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested with `pynput` and used [pyWinhook](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pywinhook). The `Injected` is a flag for determining if the click was triggered by a program, not a user.

```
import threading
import pyautogui
import pyWinhook
import pythoncom

clickCount = 0

def onclick(event):
    global clickCount
    print(event.__dict__)
    if event.Injected and clickCount == 1:
        clickCount = 0
        return False
    
    clickCount += 1
    
    threading.Thread(target=pyautogui.click).start()

    return True

hm = pyWinhook.HookManager()
hm.SubscribeMouseAllButtonsDown(onclick)
hm.HookMouse()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
hm.UnhookMouse()
```

Answer (score 0):

this problem arises due to an infinite loop scenario. For instance, when the left mouse button is clicked, it initiates the `on_click` function. however, if this `on_click` function itself triggers the left button click again, the system will repeatedly execute the `on_click` function, leading to an infinite loop. To address this concern, a solution involves implementing a flag to distinguish between clicks made by the user and those triggered by the system. By doing so, the `on_click` function will only be invoked if the click originates from the user.

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener
import pyautogui
import time

clicked = False

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global clicked
    if button == button.left and pressed:
        if not clicked:
            print("User Clicked!")
            clicked = True
            time.sleep(0.1)
            pyautogui.click()
            
        else:
            print("System Clicked!")
            clicked = False 
        

with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Nope, still lags on Windows. The problem is not caused by an infinite loop.